# css submit button background image

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image into the submit button. I've added a picture but when i do `no-repeat` background image disappears! What should I do to avoid losing image ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="comtextarea">
  <textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  id="" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="" class="combut"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .comtextarea {
      float:left;
      width:550px;
      height:auto;
    }
    .comment {
      width:550px;
      resize:none;
      outline:none;
      border:1px solid #abc7d0; 
    }
    .combut {
      float:right;
      margin-top:-36px;
      z-inde:3;
      position:relative; 
      outline:none;
      width:30px;
      height:30px;
      background-image:url(https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg) no-repeat;
      padding:0px 0 4px 0; border:none;
      text-indent:-10000em; 
}
```

This is [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/sLynv) page

Comment: `background-image` will only hold the image url. You can either include all background properties into `background` or keep your current setting and add `background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because your setting it against property `background-image`.

The `background-image` property is just for specifying the background image value, no other background related properties.

Change this to `background` instead.

Or have 2 seperate properties:

```
background-image: url(..URL HERE..);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Personally I prefer 2 seperate properties. It's clearer to see the `no-repeat` value being applied, and is more manageable under source control changes.

Comment: Agreed with your suggestion for having separate properties! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a bit wrong, change:

```
background-image:url(https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg) no-repeat;
```

to:

```
background:url(https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hqIxd

Answer (score -1):

use to `background` if you used to all property in your css as like `repeat` `position`

if your used to `background-image` than **define only** `image url` as like this

```
background-image: url('some.jpg');
```

### ---------------------

**replace to this**

```
background-image:url(https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg) no-repeat;
```

**into this**

```
background:url('https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg') no-repeat;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23C4K/1/)**

### -----------------

**or used to this**

```
background-image:url('https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: yest dear you are true but i am using `background-image` because of i want to add a `background-color` into my submit button. If i use your code for my submit button `background:url(...);` is not working on that time.

Comment: than used to background-image:url('YourImageUrl'); and background-repeat:no-repeat; used to this